# What do you use Waves Enigma for?

Tags: plug-ins, creativity, techniques, mixing, sound-design

It's a pretty rad lil' plug, I was just wondering what kind of creative purposes you have used it for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more of a discussion thread from Social Sound Design than an actual question.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this page](http://www.waves.com/Content.aspx?id=5242#presets) for a list of artist presets that may make Enigma more useful to you.

EDIT: Think that list has moved [here](http://www.waves.com/downloads/free-plugin-presets)

Comment: Hahah, I pop this plugin on from time to time and then end up taking it off after a matter of seconds.  Going to check out these presets.  Thanks.